# How to find UMVUE

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, sufficient-statistics

[image]

I understand that for part A, we can show that Y is sufficient using the exponential family form. I also understand that for B, we must now use this statistic to find an unbiased UMVUE for theta. How do we go about showing this? Would it not be Y/n? And I have no idea how to do C so any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you studied Rao-Blackwell theorem?

Comment: Yes, I believe B has to do with applying the Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem but I'm unsure what needs to be written.

Comment: The usual approach is to take an unbiased estimator, condition it on the complete sufficient.

Comment: Since this is poisson, $E(Y) = n \theta$, so $Y/n$ as you suggest would be unbiased.

Comment: Ok, I get that now, but how do we go about part C?

Comment: For the last part, a hint: $\eta = 1- P(X_i=0)$

Comment: I still haven't quite figured it out, but I understand why that hint is true

Comment: Is the UMVUE for part C e (as in the number e)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part c) expanding on the hint, fix one of the observations $X_i$ (any one of the $n$ will do). WLOG, let it be $X_1$ and let an estimator be

$$W=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }X_1 \geq 1 \\ \\
0 & \text{if }X_1 = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
Then $EW = P(X_1 \geq 1) = 1- P(X_1 =0) = 1-\exp(-\theta) = \eta$. So $W$ is an unbiased estimator (even though not a "sensible" one) of $\eta$. Now do "Rao-Blackwellizing", i.e., find $E(W \, | \, Y = y)$. The result will be UMVUE for $\eta$.

Comment: Using this, I computed it to be $$((n-1)/n)^Y$$