# UMVUE of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, sufficient-statistics

[image]

I know how to show that Y is complete and sufficient for part A using the exponential family form, but how do I get the UMVUE for part B?

I know we probably use Y and go for an unbiased function of Y, but I simply do not know how to get this.

Comment: check this one. using the same techniques, you will be able to solve your problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328663/uniformly-most-powerful-test/1348212#1348212

Comment: That's a UMP Test problem, I'm trying to figure out part B. Does anyone know how to find the UMVUE of that?

Comment: let $Y=f(\theta)=\theta^s+(1-\theta)^{n-s}$. Then, we also have $\theta=f^{-1}(Y)=g(Y)$. Put $\theta=g(Y)$ in $f(x,\theta)$ and derive the UMVUE as usual. After you find $g(Y)=h(\mathbf{X})$, the UMVUE for $Y$ is then $Y=g^{-1}(h(\mathbf{X}))=f(h(\mathbf{X}))$

Comment: This is just like the other assignment you posted. See the provided expanded hint in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2285928/. First find a "silly" unbiased estimator, say $V$ that will have $EV=\theta^s + (1-\theta)^{n-s}$. Then do "Rao-Blackwellizing" $E(V \, | \, Y=y)$. This will give the UMVUE.